# Ubuntu 20.04 software center says I have software installed

Tags: package-management

Ubuntu 20.04 software center says I have software installed, when I try to uninstall it, I get "Unable to remove "Hugin Panorama Creator":no packages to remove.
This application is not in my menu.

Details
Version: 2019.2.0+dfsg-1build3
Updated: Never
License:Free
Source: ubuntu-focal-universe
Installed Size: 1.3 MB
Age Rating Early Childhood

Comment: If Ubuntu Software says you have it installed, scroll down that page to the 'Details" section. Copy those fields and paste them into your Question above.